# why JEST test fails due to closing browser by puppeteer

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer

I am using JEST + Puppeteer to run functional tests on hosted web app.

here is test code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const url = 'https://somewebsite.com';

const login = (async(page, login, password) =>{
  await page.goto(url)
  await page.waitForSelector('#mat-input-0')
  await page.type('#mat-input-0', login)
  await page.type('#mat-input-1', password)
  await page.click('button')

})


beforeEach(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    page = await browser.newPage();
});

afterEach(async () => {
    await browser.close();
});

describe('login to website test', () => {
  test('non existent user try', async() => {
    jest.setTimeout(300000);

    await login(page, 'user@email.com', 'upsiforgoTTThepassword')
    await page.waitFor(1000)
    var element  = await page.$eval('.mat-simple-snackbar', (element) => {
      return element.textContent.trim()
    })

    expect(element).toBe('User not Found')

  })
})
```

And the problem I got is, that if I use puppeteer function `await browser.close();` to exit browser after test ends It is automatically failed and I get the error in terminal:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Protocol error: Connection closed. Most likely the page has been closed.
```

and if I don't close browser after test ends it passes as it should.

Comment: I've tried your code (just changed the login() and page.$eval for my test and everything works. no "Connection closed" message.

Comment: so maybe the issue is in my test env configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out if I comment out preset in my jest.config.js, the error stops to occur:

```
// preset: "jest-puppeteer",
```